# Mingw64 version check

Tags: mingw, mingw-w64

do you know how to check the version of mingw64, not the version of gcc/g++ but of mingw64 itself ?

I wondered if there's was any type of command or something to check the version, but there wasn't any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For MinGW-w64 the following are defined:

- `__MINGW64_VERSION_MAJOR`
- `__MINGW64_VERSION_MINOR`
- `__MINGW64_VERSION_BUGFIX`

So the following C program will show the MinGW-w64 version.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  printf("MinGW-w64 version %i.%i.%i\n", __MINGW64_VERSION_MAJOR, __MINGW64_VERSION_MINOR, __MINGW64_VERSION_BUGFIX);
  return 0;
}
```

Note that this is specifically for MinGW-w64, for plain old MinGW it won't work. So you can use `#ifdef __MINGW64_VERSION_MAJOR` to detect of your using MinGW-w64 instead of MinGW.

Comment: Hey man, thanks a lot for the answer. As I know the latest version of mingw64 is 10.0.0, but my one (by the msys2), is showing 11.0.0 . Is it ok?

Comment: At this time MinGW-w64 11 is not released yet, but maybe your version uses a snapshot version.